# Displaying a value in a text box-Error

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have 
      size_t sums[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

and a text box in which I am trying to display the value that I get after I've done some operations on it. The value is in sums[i] , however now I want to display the value in the textbox, I am doing this:

```
  *TextBox4 << "hello" << size_t sums;

frame->Connect(TEXT_BOX4, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED | wxEVT_COMMAND_ENTER, (wxObjectEventFunction) & MyFrame::OnGenerateKey);

TextBox4 = new wxTextCtrl(this, TEXT_BOX4, wxT(""), wxPoint(200, 200), wxSize(200, 20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_READONLY | wxTE_LEFT, wxDefaultValidator, wxT("WxTextBox4"));
```

however it generates the following  errors

```
 base.cpp:212:22: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in '*((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::TextBox4 << sum'
base.cpp:212:22: note: candidates are:
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:419:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(const wxString&)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:420:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(int)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:421:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(long int)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:422:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(float)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:423:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(double)
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/textctrl.h:424:17: note: wxTextCtrl& wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(wxChar)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Shouldn't TextBox have some sort of function like set value or sth?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not print a static array like that, you need to iterate over it. Second - you should only print sums without the type:

> *TextBox4 << "hello" << sums;

Still this may not be enough to help you - I need more context.

Comment: I tried with this too as you said and it generates the following error
base.cpp:221:33: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in '((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::TextBox4->wxTextCtrl::<anonymous>.wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<((* & wxString(((const char*)"hello")))) << sums'

Comment: As I said you can not print an array just like that. Could you try the code above with `*TextBox4 << "hello" << sums[0];` and tell me what is the result. Also please provide some info on what IS TextBox(what type).

Comment: sums[0] will only print the first element. If you need to print all of them, you need to use a cycle like: `for(int i=0;i<4;++i) *TextBox<<sums[i];` I only proposed to you to try to print sums[0] so that I can investigate the error

Comment: This post does not provide any information. In what way does it not work? What error do you get? And WHAT is the type of TextBox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14120/discussion-between-izomorphius-and-emma-rochweel)